# Android http-request causes Error - sitting since 3 days

Tags: android, http-request

I am sitting since 3 days, looking everywhere on net but it dosnt work ... every time I try to make a http-request on android: it comes the error: unfourtunately, ... has stopped. here my code:

```
package sd.s;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class SdsdActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Thread trd = new Thread(new Runnable(){ 
              public void run(){ 
                  // Creating HTTP client 
                    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
                    // Creating HTTP Post 
                    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost( 
                            "http://www.test.com"); 

                    // Building post parameters 
                    // key and value pair 
                    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2); 
                    nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("test", "test")); 
                    nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message", 
                            "Hi, trying Android HTTP post!")); 

                    // Url Encoding the POST parameters 
                    try { 
                        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair)); 
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) { 
                        // writing error to Log 
                        e.printStackTrace(); 
                    } 

                    // Making HTTP Request 
                    try { 
                        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost); 

                        // writing response to log 
                        Log.d("Http Response:", response.toString()); 
                    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) { 
                        // writing exception to log 
                        e.printStackTrace(); 
                    } catch (IOException e) { 
                        // writing exception to log 
                        e.printStackTrace(); 

                    } 
              } });
            trd.run(); 


    }
}
```

here my output on LogCat

```
02-24 17:53:39.003: D/dalvikvm(516): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
02-24 17:53:40.293: D/AndroidRuntime(516): Shutting down VM
02-24 17:53:40.304: W/dalvikvm(516): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
02-24 17:53:40.313: E/AndroidRuntime(516): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-24 17:53:40.313: E/AndroidRuntime(516): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{sd.s/sd.s.SdsdActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
02-24 17:53:40.313: E/AndroidRuntime(516):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
02-24 17:53:40.313: E/AndroidRuntime(516):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
02-24 17:53:40.313: E/AndroidRuntime(516):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
02-24 17:53:40.313: E/AndroidRuntime(516):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
02-24 17:53:40.313: E/AndroidRuntime(516):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-24 17:53:40.313: E/AndroidRuntime(516):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-24 17:53:40.313: E/AndroidRuntime(516):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
02-24 17:53:40.313: E/AndroidRuntime(516):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-24 17:53:40.313: E/AndroidRuntime(516):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-24 17:53:40.313: E/AndroidRuntime(516):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
02-24 17:53:40.313: E/AndroidRuntime(516):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
02-24 17:53:40.313: E/AndroidRuntime(516):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-24 17:53:40.313: E/AndroidRuntime(516): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
02-24 17:53:40.313: E/AndroidRuntime(516):  at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1099)
02-24 17:53:40.313: E/AndroidRuntime(516):  at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:391)
02-24 17:53:40.313: E/AndroidRuntime(516):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:242)
02-24 17:53:40.313: E/AndroidRuntime(516):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:220)
02-24 17:53:40.313: E/AndroidRuntime(516):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
02-24 17:53:40.313: E/AndroidRuntime(516):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
02-24 17:53:40.313: E/AndroidRuntime(516):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
02-24 17:53:40.313: E/AndroidRuntime(516):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
02-24 17:53:40.313: E/AndroidRuntime(516):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
02-24 17:53:40.313: E/AndroidRuntime(516):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
02-24 17:53:40.313: E/AndroidRuntime(516):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
02-24 17:53:40.313: E/AndroidRuntime(516):  at sd.s.SdsdActivity.onCreate(SdsdActivity.java:52)
02-24 17:53:40.313: E/AndroidRuntime(516):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
02-24 17:53:40.313: E/AndroidRuntime(516):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
02-24 17:53:40.313: E/AndroidRuntime(516):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
02-24 17:53:40.313: E/AndroidRuntime(516):  ... 11 more
02-24 17:59:31.783: D/AndroidRuntime(584): Shutting down VM
02-24 17:59:31.783: W/dalvikvm(584): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
02-24 17:59:31.793: E/AndroidRuntime(584): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-24 17:59:31.793: E/AndroidRuntime(584): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{sd.s/sd.s.SdsdActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
02-24 17:59:31.793: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
02-24 17:59:31.793: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
02-24 17:59:31.793: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
02-24 17:59:31.793: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
02-24 17:59:31.793: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-24 17:59:31.793: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-24 17:59:31.793: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
02-24 17:59:31.793: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-24 17:59:31.793: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-24 17:59:31.793: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
02-24 17:59:31.793: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
02-24 17:59:31.793: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-24 17:59:31.793: E/AndroidRuntime(584): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
02-24 17:59:31.793: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1099)
02-24 17:59:31.793: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:391)
02-24 17:59:31.793: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:242)
02-24 17:59:31.793: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:220)
02-24 17:59:31.793: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
02-24 17:59:31.793: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
02-24 17:59:31.793: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
02-24 17:59:31.793: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
02-24 17:59:31.793: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
02-24 17:59:31.793: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
02-24 17:59:31.793: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
02-24 17:59:31.793: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at sd.s.SdsdActivity$1.run(SdsdActivity.java:53)
02-24 17:59:31.793: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
02-24 17:59:31.793: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at sd.s.SdsdActivity.onCreate(SdsdActivity.java:66)
02-24 17:59:31.793: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
02-24 17:59:31.793: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
02-24 17:59:31.793: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
02-24 17:59:31.793: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  ... 11 more
02-24 18:08:12.242: D/AndroidRuntime(626): Shutting down VM
02-24 18:08:12.242: W/dalvikvm(626): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
02-24 18:08:12.262: E/AndroidRuntime(626): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-24 18:08:12.262: E/AndroidRuntime(626): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{sd.s/sd.s.SdsdActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
02-24 18:08:12.262: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
02-24 18:08:12.262: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
02-24 18:08:12.262: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
02-24 18:08:12.262: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
02-24 18:08:12.262: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-24 18:08:12.262: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-24 18:08:12.262: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
02-24 18:08:12.262: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-24 18:08:12.262: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-24 18:08:12.262: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
02-24 18:08:12.262: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
02-24 18:08:12.262: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-24 18:08:12.262: E/AndroidRuntime(626): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
02-24 18:08:12.262: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1099)
02-24 18:08:12.262: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:391)
02-24 18:08:12.262: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:242)
02-24 18:08:12.262: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:220)
02-24 18:08:12.262: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
02-24 18:08:12.262: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
02-24 18:08:12.262: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
02-24 18:08:12.262: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
02-24 18:08:12.262: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
02-24 18:08:12.262: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
02-24 18:08:12.262: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
02-24 18:08:12.262: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at sd.s.SdsdActivity$1.run(SdsdActivity.java:53)
02-24 18:08:12.262: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
02-24 18:08:12.262: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at sd.s.SdsdActivity.onCreate(SdsdActivity.java:66)
02-24 18:08:12.262: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
02-24 18:08:12.262: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
02-24 18:08:12.262: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
02-24 18:08:12.262: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  ... 11 more
```

Maybe I am to stupid but since 3 days I trying to get it running, The Applications starts, but stops after start everytime ...
Permission Internet is done and Firewall is np > WebBrowser in emulator works as well, what is wrong? pls - thank you very much for every answer!

Answer (score 2):

You are executing the run() method of your Thread object on the main thread. Replace this:

```
trd.run();
```

with this:

```
trd.start();
```

Comment: Nice catch. I'd looked at that code for several minutes and couldn't see what was wrong. Doh!

Answer (score 2):

As of Android 3.0, you cannot perform this type of request on the main thread.

> NetworkOnMainThreadException
>
> Class Overview
>
> The exception that is thrown when an application attempts to perform a networking operation on its main thread.
>
> This is only thrown for applications targeting the Honeycomb SDK or higher. Applications targeting earlier SDK versions are allowed to do networking on their main event loop threads, but it's heavily discouraged. See the document Designing for Responsiveness.
>
> Also see StrictMode.

See http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/responsiveness.html for guidelines on building responsive applications.

Comment: _"As of Android 3.0, ..."_ -- it was also a very bad idea before 3.0; it was just not enforced automatically by the framework before then. (Since 2.3, you could also use [StrictMode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html) to catch these kinds of problems. It's still a good idea to use StrictMode.)

Answer (score 0):

From your log, it looks like the error is android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException. From http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html, it sounds like the error is that you're trying to do network operations in your main thread. Since this can make your UI unresponsive, it's discouraged. And since you seem to be running in strict mode (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html), it's crashing the app.

Also, you should be calling trd.start() instead of trd.run()